# Calling Cython C functions from Python

Tags: python, cython

I have a [`Cython`](http://cython.org/) file called `foo.pyx` containing the following functions:

```
def add_one(int n):
    cdef int m = n + 1
    return m

cdef int c_add_one(int n):
    return n + 1
```

I build this `pyx` file using `cython -a foo.pyx` and can then do:

```
>>> import foo
>>> foo.add_one(5)
6
>>> foo.c_add_one(5)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'c_add_one'
```

So it looks like I can't call `c_add_one` from python. What are the advantages of declaring a function using `cdef`?

Comment: `cdef` defines a function that can be accessed _only_ from C. If you want `c_add_one` to be accessible from Python, you should use `cpdef` instead. The advantage is of `cdef` is to remove the overhead of the python layer when calling it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. **Speed**: Cython and C can call `cdef` and `cpdef` functions much faster than regular functions.  Regular `def` functions are full-blown Python objects.  They require reference counting, the GIL, etc.
2. **Encapsulation**: If a function is declared `cdef`, it will not be exposed to Python users.  This is beneficial if the function was never intended for public consumption (e.g. because it doesn't check its parameters, or relates to an implementation detail which might change in the future).  Users can still circumvent this via C/Cython, of course, but doing so is more of a hassle than most will bother with.  In this way, it's similar to double-underscore name mangling.